# Sqlite View : Add a column based on some other column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables

**Employee**

```
ID | Name | Department
----------------------
121  |Name1  | dep1
223  |Name2  | dep2
```

**Assignment**

```
ID | EID| 
---------
1  |121
2  |223
3  |121
```

[other columns omitted for brevity]

The table assignment indicates which is work is assigned to whom.EID is a foriegn key to the table Employee.Also it is possible to have two work assigned to the same employee.

Now  i want to create a view like this

```
EID | Assigned
--------------
121 |true
333 |false
```

Assigned column should be calculated based on the entries in the Assignment table.

So far i am only successful in creating a view like this

```
EID | Assigned
--------------
121 |2
333 |0
```

using the command

```
CREATE VIEW "AssignmentView" AS
SELECT distinct ID ,(select Count(*)
from Assignment where Assignment.EID = Employee.ID) as Assigned
FROM  Employee;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CASE` expression and a `GROUP BY` should do the trick:

```
Select
  e.id,
  Case When Count(a.eid) > 0 Then 'true' Else 'false' End As assigned
From employee e
Left Join assignment a On ( a.eid = e.id )
Group By e.id;
```